Capacity provider not scaling ASG on ECS deployment
I am building an ECS on EC2 service. I want to implement a blue/green deployment where every time I deploy a new version of my app, ECS temporarily doubles the amount of tasks to host the new version, and terminates the old ones once the new ones are up and running.
This is a pretty common way of deploying applications to ensure no downtime for users.
As suggested by the AWS blogs i have read i have created this using a capacity provider. So my cdk project had the following constructs
const autoscalingGroup = new AutoScalingGroup(this, `${this.id}-autoscaling-group`, {
    maxCapacity: 2,
    minCapacity: 1,
    minHealthyPercentage: 100,
    maxHealthyPercentage: 200,
    desiredCapacity: 1,
    ...
})

capacityProvider = new AsgCapacityProvider(this, `${this.id}-capacity-provider`, {
    autoScalingGroup: autoscalingGroup,
    enableManagedScaling: true,
    enableManagedTerminationProtection: true,
})

cluster = new Cluster(this, `${this.id}-ecs-cluster`, {
    ...
})

cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider)

new Ec2Service(this, `${this.id}-ec2-service`, {
    cluster: ecsCluster,
...
})


This CDK code effectively creates two pieces of infrastructures and connects them with each other.
An ECS cluster and service responsible to spin up new tasks for my application, and an ASG responsible to spin up servers for my application tasks to sit on. (Fargate could remove the need to worry about this second layer, but that's besides the point).
Finally, this also creates a capacity provider and assigns it to the cluster so that the cluster knows where to find EC2 instances for its ECS services.
On my first deploy everythign works just fine -- ASG spins up a new EC2 instance, and ECS spins up a task and places on it.
The problem arises on any subsequent deploys. At this point i would expect ECS to tell ASG to scale up one more instance to fit one more task (in my setup each instance fits 1 task). This doesnt happen tho, and ECS remains stuck not able to find a valid instance to place a new task on.

Did you find a solution to this?

yup, it's the answer to this question. See below.

The problem with the setup above is that it is missing a key component; a bond between ECS service and the capacity provider:
new Ec2Service(this, `${this.id}-ec2-service`, {
    cluster: ecsCluster,
    taskDefinition: this.props.taskDefinition,
    // it's important to link this specific ECS service to the capacity provider.
    // only linking the cluster doesn't allow this service to trigger ASG events
    capacityProviderStrategies: [{
        capacityProvider: capacityProvider.capacityProviderName,
        weight: 1,
        base: 1
    }]
})

In fact, while giving the cluster access to the capacity provider allows it services to place tasks on the instances, it doesnt allow a single service to trigger a scale up and down. To do that, you need to tell the ECSService itself what capacity provider to use by adding a capacity provider strategy. More on the specific settings for the strategy can be found here
